# Send Text Messages to Numbers Retrieved from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send Text msgs to Numbers present in my Database. 
The msgs should be delivered when tapped on an imageView.
The following code in inside a fragment called Tab33.
I am sharing just the onClick method for ImageViews

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.imageViewPayments:

            Boolean b = checkPermission();

            if(b==true) {
                DBRef.child("Members").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String phn = dataSnapshot.child("memberPhone").getValue(String.class);
                        String no = "+91 ";
                        String cat = no.concat(phn);
                        sms.sendTextMessage(cat, null, "Hey there! We know you enjoy Canteen Food but nobody likes to be in debt and that too for food. Please"  +
                                " pay your Canteen Bill to the earliest and stay a Happy Tummy!", null, null);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Message Sent Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Snackbar.make(getView(), "Permission to send message NOT granted!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }

            return;

        case R.id.imageViewToday:





            return;

        case R.id.imageViewCoupon:



            return;

        case R.id.imageViewComposeMessage:
            Snackbar.make(getView(), "Compose Message!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            return;

    }

}

private boolean checkPermission()
{
    String permission = Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;
    int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

where  `DBRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`
and    `sms = SmsManager.getDefault();`

The Toast is showing up and then the app crashes.

[image: database]

Comment: can you debug the app so you can share the errors android studio showing?

Answer (score 0):

When you load nodes with a `ValueEventListener` the snapshot you get in `onDataChange` contains all matching child nodes. To get to the individual user nodes, you will need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`.

Something like:

```
DBRef.child("Members").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
      String phn = childSnapshot.child("memberPhone").getValue(String.class);
      System.out.println(phn)
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors!
  }
```